# exosip_automatic_action fails to re-initiate call upon 4xx reception via TCP

Tags: c++, sip, voip, exosip

For a SIP call INVITE request via TCP, if we get a 401 from the registrar, the call re-invite with authentication fails in exosip.

Ideally, the exosip_automatic_action should handle this (and it does get called) but the following problem stops it from proceeding further.

```
  /* an EARLY dialog may have failed with 401,407 or 3Xx */
  osip_transaction_t *out_tr = NULL;

  out_tr = jc->c_out_tr; // where eXosip_call_t *jc;
```

in this case, the re-invite will be sent if, the call state is `COMPLETED` and the `out_tr->last_response` is either 401 or 407

However, I can see that the call state coming my way is either PROCEEDING or CALLING and the `out_tr->last_response` is `NULL`.

If I use UDP, this never happens. It is only happening for TCP or TLS.

Answer (score 0):

There are some use-cases where **eXosip_automatic_action** can't work. This is by design.

Instead, for the use-case you hit, you need to use such code when you receive the **EXOSIP_CALL_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE** event with a negative "did" parameter:

```
  if (exosip_event->type == EXOSIP_CALL_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE && exosip_event->did < 0) {
    if (exosip_event->response != NULL && (exosip_event->response->status_code == 407 || exosip_event->response->status_code == 401))
      eXosip_default_action (exosip_event);
  }
```

The above code is to be added within your *"exosip event loop"*.

**eXosip_default_action** should do the automatic missing retry!

EDIT: sorry, this needs also to be done for event **EXOSIP_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE**:

```
if (exosip_event->type == EXOSIP_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE && exosip_event->request != NULL) {
  if (exosip_event->response != NULL) {
    if (MSG_IS_PUBLISH (exosip_event->request)) {
    } else if (exosip_event->response->status_code == 407 || exosip_event->response->status_code == 401)
        eXosip_default_action (exosip_event);
  }
}
```

EDIT2: It is possible that, if you call **eXosip_automatic_action** too late, then the transaction is turned into COMPLETED before you actually execute the **eXosip_automatic_action** method?

This is an extract from my own code, showing **WHEN** the method must be called.

```
je = eXosip_event_wait (tv_s, tv_ms);
eXosip_lock ();
eXosip_automatic_action ();
```

-I'm the author of osip/exosip-

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I am getting EXOSIP_CALL_REQUESTFAILURE and If I try and call exosip_default_action on this, the call fails.

Comment: the error being ```call dialog not found``` if I forcefully call ```eXosip_default_action```

Comment: Sorry: I have edited my answer to also include **EXOSIP_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE** which needs the same code.

Comment: I'm not able to understand the reason you face the issue with **EXOSIP_CALL_REQUESTFAILURE**. This is not happening for my own implementation... May be you are calling **eXosip_automatic_action** too late in the process?

Comment: Regarding the call to ```eXosip_automatic_action();```
- I am actually calling it the same way you are doing it in your code. So that won't be an issue I guess.

Comment: My scenario is: I send out an INVITE without authentication, get a 401 from the registrar server, and then need to send another INVITE with authentication. The second part should work automatically but it does not. However, when I am using UDP, it works. It fails intermittently for TCP and TLS. While debugging, I saw that the ```eXosip_automatic_action``` does get called but the call state is either ```CALLING``` or ```PROCEEDING``` which does not let the INVITE with authentication go through. For this to work, the call state should be ```COMPLETED```

Comment: I have read again your question, and I have also tested what is happening for TCP and TLS: out_tr->last_response can't be NULL if you receive a 401. Additionnaly, in my test with TLS, the state is ICT_TERMINATED in **eXosip_automatic_action**.

Comment: Exactly!!! ```out_tr->last_response``` is NULL and the call state is ```CALLING``` or ```PROCEEDING``` thats what the issue it.. Do let me know if you have a fix for this :)

Comment: Please go on the mailing list of osip and ask me the question there. With more details on code and version... Tks

Comment: I couldn't find a valid mailing list so I emailed the query to your email ID, which I found in the exosip source code :)
Please help me with the mailing list in case you want me to post the query there.